# What are the respective purposes of the emberjs.com and ember-cli websites?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am a bit confused regarding the ember websites "emberjs.com" and "ember-cli.com". Isn't ember-cli now a part of emberjs and documented at "emberjs.com"? If so, why have a different website for ember-cli? Also, why do the sites differ regarding the versions of the prerequisite JS frameworks? For example, the emberjs.com getting starting page says to use Node.js 0.12 or higher while the ember-cli.com site says to use the latest stable version of Node (version 4.0.x).

Answer (score 0):

> the emberjs.com getting starting page says to use Node.js 0.12 or
>   higher while the ember-cli.com site says to use the latest stable
>   version of Node (version 4.0.x).

Seems like emberjs.com is out of sync, you can create issue on emberjs.com website repository on GitHub or hope that it's already created and it will be resolved shortly. Also, there was as [issue with `bufferutil`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4873) in Ember CLI + node.js 4.0, so they might wait until it's resolved, but for some reason it's recommended on `ember-cli.com`.

> Isn't ember-cli now a part of emberjs and documented at "emberjs.com"?

It isn't part of Ember.js. It's part of Ember.js ecosystem. It's recommended tool to work with library and that's why examples in guides assume that you're using Ember CLI. But, you could also use Ember.js without Ember CLI by loading jQuery, Ember.js, Ember.js template compiler and working on globals.

Ember.js documents everything about library itself, how logic behind library works, core concepts. You have components, routing, controllers, models explained there, but you won't find information there how to add CoffeeScript to your project.

Ember CLI website documents everything about Ember CLI, which is tool that provides:

- asset pipeline
- a strong conventional project structure
- powerful addon system for extension.

You can see in [user-guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/) that it documents possible build configurations, how to make SASS or CoffeeScript working in your environment etc.

Comment: I did understand that ember-cli wasn't exactly part of emberjs, but is instead, as you say, part of emberjs ecosystem. But, being part of the ecosystem and the recommended way of using emberjs, I don't understand why ember-cli has it's own distinct website. My concern was that one site was obsolete or that there were competing interests and directions. Being new to node development, I didn't realize that the node version numbers had been changing so fast lately, so maybe the version differences are no big deal. Strange though that the numbering has been changing so fast.